# Vue Transition on picture/img element not fading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition, fadein, fadeout

I have a Vue component that uses swiper.js for some slides - the effect is to have an image come from right to left and go from about 300x300px to fill the screen, then content such at a title and description overlay the text.

How I have currently got it working is to bring the image in from right to left and after it gets to fill the screen the image will fade and disappear. just before disappearing the component has a background image which is then swapped out with the image from the new slide it should do it so it looks like it's blended into the background. this works quite well. however, the issue I have noticed is on the reverse. when I attempt to rewind the animation the background image is just flipping the image instantly and not recognising the fade transition that's on that element.

I want to know if there is something I am doing wrong, please see my code below you can see that there is a picture element with an image - this image will get updated and should do it with the fade. going forward isn't a problem as it is technically hidden but the transition isn't working at all.

```
<template>
  <div class="c-screen">
    <div class="c-screen__background" :class="backgroundColourClass">
      <div v-if="showDesktopLeftGradient" class="c-screen__desktop-left-gradient" />
      <div v-if="showDesktopRightGradient" class="c-screen__desktop-right-gradient" />
      <div v-if="showDesktopRightFeather" class="c-screen__desktop-right-feather" />
      <svg v-if="!hideWatermark" class="c-screen__background-overlay" :class="[watermarkColourClass]" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
           viewBox="0 0 233.1 233.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 233.1 233.2;" xml:space="preserve"
      >
        <use :href="backgroundUrl" />
      </svg>
      <transition name="fade" appear mode="out-in">
        <picture class="c-screen__background-media-frame" :class="backgroundImageColourClass" v-if="backgroundImage" :key="activeBackgroundIndex">
          <img class="c-screen__background-media" :style="{ opacity: backgroundMediaOpacity }" :src="backgroundImage">
          <div />
        </picture>
      </transition>
      <div class="c-screen__background-media-frame" :class="backgroundImageColourClass" v-if="backgroundVideo">
        <video class="c-screen__background-media" :style="{ opacity: backgroundMediaOpacity }" loop autoplay muted playsinline>
          <source :src="backgroundVideo">
        </video>
        <div />
      </div>
      <div class="c-screen__frame" :class="screenOverflowClass">
        <screen-header :text-colour="textColour" />
        <div class="c-screen__content" :class="[screenContentClass]">
          <slot name="content" />
        </div>
        <div v-if="tipMessage || showNavigationArrows" class="c-screen__controls" :class="{ 'c-screen__controls--left' : alignNavigationArrowsLeft }">
          <navigation-arrows :text-colour="textColour" :auto-play-screen-initial="autoPlayScreenInitial" :align-navigation-arrows-left="alignNavigationArrowsLeft" v-if="showNavigationArrows" />
          <transition name="fade-up" appear>
            <tip v-if="tipMessage" :content="tipMessage" />
          </transition>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import screenHeader from './header.vue'
import navigationArrows from './navigation-arrows.vue'
import tip from './tip.vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            backgroundUrl: '/dist/images/icons.svg#icon-connect'
        }
    },
    props: {
        showNavigationArrows: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false
        },
        tipMessage: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        backgroundColour: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        backgroundImage: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        backgroundVideo: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        backgroundMediaOpacity: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1,
            required: false
        },
        hideWatermark: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: false
        },
        showDesktopLeftGradient: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: false
        },
        showDesktopRightGradient: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
            required: false
        },
        screenContentClass: {
            type: [String, Array],
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        screenOverflow: {
            type: String,
            default: '',
            required: false
        },
        backgroundIndex: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1,
            required: false
        },
        alignNavigationArrowsLeft: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false
        },
        autoPlayScreenInitial: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false
        }
    },
    components: {
        screenHeader,
        navigationArrows,
        tip
    },
    computed: {
        activeBackgroundIndex() {
            if(this.backgroundIndex) {
                return this.backgroundIndex
            }
            return 1
        },
        backgroundColourClass() {
            if(this.backgroundColour) {
                return `c-screen__background--${this.backgroundColour}`
            }
            return ''
        },
        backgroundImageColourClass() {
            if(this.backgroundColour) {
                return `c-screen__background-media-frame--${this.backgroundColour}`
            }
            return ''
        },
        watermarkColourClass() {
            if(this.watermarkColour) {
                return `c-screen__background-overlay--${this.watermarkColour}`
            }
            return ''
        },
        headingColourClass() {
            if(this.textColour) {
                return `c-screen__heading--${this.textColour}`
            }
            return ''
        },
        textColour() {
            if(this.backgroundColour === 'regant-gray' || this.backgroundColour === 'prussian-blue' || this.backgroundColour === 'brand-gradient') {
                return 'white'
            }
            return ''
        },
        showDesktopRightFeather() {
            if(this.backgroundColour === 'brand-gradient') {
                return true
            }
            return false
        },
        watermarkColour() {
            if(this.backgroundColour === 'white') {
                return 'gray'
            }
            return ''
        },
        screenOverflowClass() {
            if(this.screenOverflow) {
                return `c-screen__frame--${this.screenOverflow}`
            }
            return ''
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Please let me know if more information is required - I have tried looking around but I don't see what's causing the issue. both picture and img both have display block and a set height of 100%.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It works with special transition classes in CSS (according to [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions)). In case of `picture` element, you need to create CSS rules also for nested `img` elements. See the snippet below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    images: [
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643865420039-0c4d77d0553f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80",
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1643967377110-c17a5ddf14f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80"
    ],
    currentSlide: 0
  },
  mounted: function () {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.currentSlide++
      if (this.currentSlide === this.images.length) {
        this.currentSlide = 0
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
})
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide-fade-enter-active img {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide-fade-leave-active img {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-fade-enter img, .slide-fade-leave-to img {
  filter: blur(10px);
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(3deg);
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-wrapper img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <transition name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
      <template v-for="(image, index) in images">
        <picture :key="`slide${index}`" alt="" v-if="currentSlide === index">
          <img :src="image" alt="">
        </picture>
      </template>
    </transition>
  </div>
</div>
```